# nil in an optional type, what exactly is behind it? what it looks like in the memory?

Tags: swift, class, pass-by-reference, option-type

```
class Person{
    let name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

var john: Person?
```

The code snippet above defines a variable of optional type named `john`. At this moment, the variable has an initial value of **nil**.

A class instance saves its value in the heap space and stores the reference in the stack. (Correct me if I'm wrong) `john` in this case is a un-assigned optional variable, it does not reference to any instance yet.

Question: Where does the PC stores the name string "john"? Has it already been created and stored in the **stack** and waiting for reference to some instance in **heap**?  And where the value "nil" stored?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### With this

```
var john: Person?
```

A slot of memory is added on top of the `Stack`.

The type of this slot is `Optional` value of type `Person`

```
Optional<Person>
```

Inside this location of memory we found the `Optional.none` value.

### After this

```
john = Person(name: "Mr Robot")
```

some memory is allocated into the `Heap`.

This memory is then written following the logic of the `Person initializer`.

Then let's get back to the Stack.
Here the `Optional.none` is replaced with the value `Optional.some` and the address memory of the `Person` object is written inside a special a field of the enum value.

Comment: Thanks for your help and explanation ")

Answer (score 3):

Behind the scenes, optionals are actually just generic `enum`s with associated values:

```
enum Optional<T> {
    case some(T)
    case none
}
```

`nil` is just shorthand for `Optional.none`. So in your example, `john` has all the storage it needs already; it's set to a value, that value just happens to *represent* nothingness. Now, since `Person` is a class, which is a reference type, "all the storage it needs" is actually just room for a pointer. The storage for your instance's properties will be created on initialization, as for all class instances.

**In conclusion:** There's memory for an `enum` with an associated pointer to a `Person` at first. Then, after you initialize the variable, there's of course a `Person` instance as well.

Comment: Therefore, till this moment `john` is an `enum`, but `enum` is by value type and class it by reference type. Can I say that after the `john` has been initialized, it becomes class instance.

Comment: Actually, `john` continues to be an `enum`, it just gains a pointer to your class instance once you initialize it. The compiler hides all this behind the `!` and `?` operators, which unwrap the associated value from inside the `enum` and let you work with it normally.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and explanation. ")